# Is there a way to subtract a number from every number in a list above another number in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I'm very new to python so hopefully this will be an easy question. I have a list with a bunch of numbers that I would like to subtract one from IF that number is above a certain other number. For example, I have the following list with 4 missing:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What can I do to decrease every number that is greater than 4 by one? I have tried a for loop:

```
for x in a:
    if x > 4:
        x-=1
print(a)
```

But that does not change anything in the list.
I have also tried list comprehensions but I am new to them so I couldn't get it to work and got errors:

```
a = [[x - 1 if x > 4] for x in a]
a = [[x - 1 for x in a] if x > 4]
```

What can I do to decrease every number above 4 by one and make that list count from one to eight?

Comment: you can try `a = [x - 1  if (x > 4) else x for x in a]`

Comment: @DOOM Sadly that gave me a SytaxError

Comment: With `[x - 1 if (x > 4) else x for x in a] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` ??

Comment: @DOOM nope! you were right silly me. I must have mistyped

Comment: @DOOM that works fine on my machine

Comment: The for loop didn't work because `x` does not retain any linkage back to the original value in the list; it's just a freestanding variable at that point, and assigning to `x` does not affect anything else.

Comment: @John Gordon ohh, thank you. I did not know that (obviously). That is really helpful because I'm sure I would have tried again otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[i-1 if i>4 else i for i in a]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly and I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for items in a list for iteration so that you can change an item's value by its index:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x > 4:
        a[i] -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[x - 1 if x>4 else x for x in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first try:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for x in a:
...     if x > 4:
...         x -= 1
```

Fails (as you stated):

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

That's because you are dealing with integers and integers are, in Python, immutable objects (floats, strings, ... are immutable to). When you write `x -= 1`, `x` is not modified, but a new `x` is created, destroying the old one:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> id_bkp = id(x) # store the "id" of x
>>> x -= 1
>>> id(x) == id_bkp # this another x!!
False
```

You can't change the elements of the lists (they are immutable). Hence you have to create a new list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b = []
>>> for x in a:
...     if x > 4:
...         b.append(x - 1)
...     else:
...         b.append(x)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It works, but you can use a shorter syntax. A list comprehension is a way to create a new list from a existing list. But you have to convert your `if/else` from a statement to an expression:

```
>>> b = []
>>> for x in a:
...     b.append(x - 1 if x > 4 else x)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And now, the list comprehension:

```
>>> b = [x - 1 if x > 4 else x for x in a]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

---

Note that if you had a list of lists, you would get a different result because lists are mutable:

```
>>> b = [[1], [2], [3], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
>>> for y in b: # y is a singleton list
...     if y[0] > 4:
...          y[0] -= 1

>>> b
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```